# Will this multithreading pattern keep a beginner from causing problems for themselves?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xna, monogame

I'm looking at trying to multithread my game for performance, but have never done multithreading in any significant capacity before. Consider me a newbie on the subject.

The game features a large list of complex organisms that frequently interact with each other and the world around them, changing the states of plants they eat, creatures they attack, offspring they produce, etc. I want to parallelize their Update() calls, including their changing each others variables.

To compensate for my inexperience, I've been trying to come up with a simple template to follow so I don't have to deal with a nightmare of threading-related issues further down the track.

```
     public class EntityStateChangeBuffer
     {
         object stateLock;

         private int myVar1;
         public int MyVar1 
         {
             set 
             { 
                 lock(stateLock)
                 {
                     myVar1 = value; 
                 }
             }
             internal get
             {
                lock (stateLock)
                {
                    return myVar1;
                }
             }
         }

         private int myVar2;
         public int MyVar2
         {
             set 
             { 
                 lock(stateLock)
                 {
                     myVar2 = value; 
                 }
            }
            internal get
            {
                lock (stateLock)
                {
                    return myVar1;
                }
            }
        }
     }

     public class EntityState
     {
         object stateLock;

         public int MyVar1 { get; private set; }
         public int MyVar2 { get; private set; }

         public void Update(EntityStateChangeBuffer changeBuffer)
         {
             // Apply external changes recieved from other threads
             MyVar1 = changeBuffer.MyVar1;
             MyVar2 = changeBuffer.MyVar2;

             //Do internal state change work
             MyVar1++;
             MyVar2--;

             changeBuffer.MyVar1 = MyVar1;
             changeBuffer.MyVar2 = MyVar2;
         }
     }
```

This code will be stored in a seperate assembly to the rest of the game, hense the internal modifiers on the get.

This *should* force me to always make changes in a safe manner, via the write-only EntityStateChangeBuffer, the locking in which will prevent concurrency issues. After those state changes are requested, they will be acted on the next time the State object calls Update().

Using this template, I will always be a frame behind when it comes to reading State information from my entities, but will be able to do work on it without modifying it from the worker threads.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

Comment: You'll want to set the stateLock to something.  E.g. `private readonly object stateLock = new object();`.  If the changeBuffer is being changed by another thread during the Update() method's execution then the values could be inconsistent.  E.g. changeBuffer.MyVar2 could be updated after `MyVar1 = changeBuffer.MyVar1;` and before `MyVar2 = changeBuffer.MyVar2;`.  Would be good to also see how the other threads will be updating changeBuffer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this code-review style question is suitable for SO.  It _may_ be relevant on another Stack Exchange site.  Please be sure to read the site's _How to Ask_ and word your question accordingly.  Good luck!